# How do I access the Help on Exact Online functions for Excel functions when using Invantive Control?

Tags: worksheet-function, invantive-control

I am creating a number of reports using Invantive Control for Excel and I would like to have an overview of the available Excel functions for Exact Online (those starting with `I_EOL_...`)

Especially I am looking for an Excel function to retrieve the balance of a specific account per fiscal year such as they appear on the balance sheet.

Neither F1 nor Help menu does me provides me with the available Excel functions for Exact Online.

How can I access Help on the Exact Online functions?

Comment: Answering your own question is nice; however the question still should be on-topic and good quality.  At first your question is off-topic asking for documentation. Second,  it's unclear as that add-in isn't well known,  please provide some background to it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I've tried to rephrase the question to better express the problem the user was having. A friend told me there should be a tag or product name so this one has been added. If you have a tip for me how to do this better? I think it could be on topic.

Comment: @MátéJuhász This is a feature from within the application, so not an off-site resource recommendation. I tried to clarify that. Can you vote to reopen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrated Help of Invantive Control does *not* include the included Excel functions for Exact Online. However, you can determine the possibilities in several ways.

The easiest way after learning the function is to just type ahead and let Excel complete it for Invantive Control. For instance, enter `I_EOL_DIV_NAME` and then press CTRL+SHIFT+A to have Excel autocomplete the arguments:

[image: Excel auto complete]

The second way is to type ahead such as `I_EOL_DIV_NAME` and then press the function wizard and you get a list of parameters:

[image: Function wizard]

The most easy way is to first log on to Exact Online:

And then go to the Modeler ribbon and choose Building Blocks:

[image: Formulas and Array Formulas]

The formulas are scalar formulas, the reports are array formulas which use SQL.

Depending on which platform you are connected to, you will see different building blocks. So on Salesforce or Freshdesk there will be no Exact Online, unless you have a connection to both Salesforce and Exact Online.

All formulas on Exact Online start of with the division code which is the Belgium 'dossier' or Dutch 'administratie'. When not specified, it defaults to the last chosen division in the web frontend of Exact Online.

When you are connected to multiple Exact Online countries / data centers, you can add the alias to enable cross-country reporting, such as: `=I_EOL_DIV_NAME("NUMBER@fr")` for data from the French data center.

PS. The formula you are looking for is probably `I_EOL_BAL_YEAR_CLOSE`:

[image: Balance on a GL Account]